# Database not creating tables for new extensions on bin/magento setup:upgrade. Declarative Schema is not up to date

Tags: database, error, extensions, setup-script, foreign-key

I installed Magento 2.3 successfully, with custom style sheet and Mageplaza Blog ext which all works fine. I wanted to install a slider module and I have done this through ssh. Composer installs the module, and enables it (see below):

**/usr/bin/php71 bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_Productslider
The following modules have been enabled:
- Mageplaza_Productslider
To make sure that the enabled modules are properly registered, run 'setup:upgrade'.
Cache cleared successfully.
Generated classes cleared successfully. Please run the 'setup:di:compile' command to generate classes.
Info: Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. To do this, run 'module:enable' with the --clear-static-content option to clear them.**

On setup:upgrade I saw this error message:

Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/code/Composer
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/code/MSP
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/code/Magento
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/code/Symfony
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/code/Yotpo
The directory '/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/pub/static/deployed_version.txt
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/pub/static/frontend
/home/sites/10a/b/bb15557fe1/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate FOREIGN KEY constraint name 'magento@002d31333398d2/MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_POST_AUTHOR_ID_MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_AUTHOR_USER_ID', query was: ALTER TABLE `mageplaza_blog_post` MODIFY COLUMN `name` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Post Name", MODIFY COLUMN `image` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Post Image", MODIFY COLUMN `views` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Post Views ", MODIFY COLUMN `url_key` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Post URL Key", MODIFY COLUMN `meta_title` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Meta Title", MODIFY COLUMN `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  COMMENT "Post Created At", MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT "Post Updated At", MODIFY COLUMN `author_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Author ID", MODIFY COLUMN `modifier_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Author ID", MODIFY COLUMN `publish_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  COMMENT "Post Updated At", ADD CONSTRAINT `MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_POST_AUTHOR_ID_MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_AUTHOR_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `mageplaza_blog_author` (`user_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE**

on static-content:deploy I got:

Execution time: 70.554099082947
-bash-4.1$ /usr/bin/php71 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB            2390/2390           ============================ 100%   11 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB         2466/2466           ============================ 100%   12 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB             2407/2407           ============================ 100%   13 secs
frontend/Fishlock/southernsculptures/en_GB 2410/2410           ============================ 100%   12 secs

**Execution time: 67.238442897797
-bash-4.1$ The following modules are outdated:
-bash: The: command not found**

The extensions I installed didn't appear in the back end or on my database and the error report said:

Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Mageplaza_Productslider data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0

I retried php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy flushing cache and reindexing but nothing changed so disabled Mageplaza_Productslider and removed the files. I cleared all the caches, re-indexed, and deleted var cache. Then ran: static-content:deploy and the error had gone from there. So I ran setup:upgrade, but the same error as above was still apparent (this is connected to the MAGEPLAZA_BLOG module that is currently running). I then ran /usr/bin/php71 bin/magento setup:db:status and I get:

Declarative Schema is not up to date
Run 'setup:upgrade' to update your DB schema and data.

How do I get rid of the ****SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate FOREIGN KEY constraint name 'magento@002d31333398d2/MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_POST_AUTHOR_ID_MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_AUTHOR_USER_ID', query was: ALTER TABLE `mageplaza_blog_post` MODIFY COLUMN `name` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Post Name", MODIFY COLUMN `image` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Post Image", MODIFY COLUMN `views` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Post Views ", MODIFY COLUMN `url_key` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Post URL Key", MODIFY COLUMN `meta_title` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Meta Title", MODIFY COLUMN `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  COMMENT "Post Created At", MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT "Post Updated At", MODIFY COLUMN `author_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Author ID", MODIFY COLUMN `modifier_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Author ID", MODIFY COLUMN `publish_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  COMMENT "Post Updated At", ADD CONSTRAINT `MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_POST_AUTHOR_ID_MAGEPLAZA_BLOG_AUTHOR_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `mageplaza_blog_author` (`user_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE**** error

and will this sort my db issue out if I do? I don't understand how the extension connected to this issue is working ok if this is the issue? I would be grateful of any insights and thankyou in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

have you get solution of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the solution for the same? I am also facing the same problem with Mageplaza blog extension.